# No output using CLI with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ubuntu, php-5.6

I'm making a Cron job in CodeIgniter and I need access to my models in order to perform it's tasks. Here's my controller code.

```
<?php
    class Cron extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function send_mail() {
            if ( PHP_SAPI !== 'cli' ) exit('No web access allowed');
            echo "Hello World";
        }
    }
```

And if I run this command on the terminal

```
php /home/path/to/project/index.php cron send_mail
```

It doesn't return anything, it's not executing the function. But if I delete the database and session libraries from the `autoload.php` file, it runs perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get any error while function not executing??

Comment: Nothing at all, is there a way to debug or log my application?

Comment: Make changes in root **index.php** to make CI in **development mode**.

Comment: Check that you aren't using any environment variables within your code. If you are you will have to set them before you call php using: ENV_VARIABLE=variable value php script.php. This is do to the fact that environment variables that are set within your http server do not get set when executing code on the cli as you are not using your http server to run the script.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola You mean the line ~21 that says `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` Yeah, it's like that.

Comment: @nullReference I'm using `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` as the environment variable, should I define it as `production`?

Comment: Negative. That is defining a php constant. I am talking about variables that are set within your http server that are commonly accessed via $_SERVER['some_var'], or get_env('some_var'). It is common practice to define the paths to your application and system directories using environment variables as paths may differ from dev/test/prod. I would scan your codebase for $_SERVER and get_env(. Also you should be able to check your system logs for errors pertaining to this delima.

Comment: @nullReference Where can I check the logs?

Comment: Yes I am talking about `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` dont change it to production it's correct.

Comment: Check if there is any 'hook' added for checking session and redirecting

Comment: umm, I wonder about this, but isn't `session` only applies to web-browser? then, when web application want to send `cookies` to you terminal, it won't be able to do anything with it. That's why CI stops executing because you cannot be identified as a web-browser?